# Installing navigation aid for users

Tags: navigation, popup, user-experience

I am concerned users might not be able to know how to use my site.

I want to make a popup box appear when certain conditions happen.  The popup box will contain text - my suggestion for what to do.

The box would be triggered, for instance,

Inactivity after a certain time
User types excessively lengthy text string into input
Different user inputs (different messages) are tied to each other in suboptimal manner

And then ideally the box would disappear if the user kills it or some other criterion is reached

Does anyone know of a system I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp ... With a bit javascript you can easily handle what you want this alert to do.